# Using .less files with React

Tags: reactjs, less

I am trying to use .less files with a minimalist React app (created with **create-react-app**). I've added `less` and `less-loader` to my *package.json* as well as a module rule in my *webpack.config.js* file. The class reference is not being added to the HTML element however (should have **class="customColor"**).

```
<p>Hello world in a custom color.</p>
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import styles from './custom.less';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p className={styles.customColor}>
          Hello world in a custom color.
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### custom.less

```
@custom-color: red;

.customColor {
  color: @custom-color;
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "less": "^3.10.3",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader',
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
        }],
    }],
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are using CRA v2 you need to eject first then modify the `webpack.config.js` file

Comment: Alternatively you can try forking CRA https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/

Comment: Ok, I ran `npm run eject` but it didn't fix the issue.  I think I was missing a `module` attribute in *webpack.config.js*, so I added it.  Still not working though ... my *webpack.config.js* file looks like this now:

`module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
        ....
`

Answer (score 18):

to use **less files** in a react project created with **create-react-app** follow these steps:

1. `npm run eject`
2. `npm i less less-loader`
3. open webpack.config.js file located at config folder created after eject script:

look at the return value of exported function(that's the main config)

find where last style-loader added which is sass-loader

```
       {
          test: sassModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders(
            {
              importLoaders: 3,
              sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              modules: {
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              },
            },
            'sass-loader'
          ),
        },
```

and add less-loader under sass-loader like this:

```
       {
          test: sassModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders(
            {
              importLoaders: 3,
              sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              modules: {
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              },
            },
            'sass-loader'
          ),
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          use: getStyleLoaders(
            {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 3,
              sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            },
            'less-loader'
          ),
          // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
          // containing package claims to have no side effects.
          // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
          // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
          sideEffects: true,
        },
```

**importLoaders** option inside less-loader should be 3.

**two loaders** from getStyleLoaders + our **less-loader**.

> The option importLoaders allows you to configure how many loaders before css-loader should be applied to @imported resources.

## why module option is true?

```
// index.less file

.header {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

if you want to use stylesheet file like this:

```
import styles from './index.less';

<div className={styles.header}></div>
```

you should set **modules: true**

but if you want to use it like below:

```
import './index.less';

<div className="header"></div>
```

you should set **modules: false**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes and [answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: This is an excellent answer and clearly saved me days of searching.  Thank you very much for the detail and the explanations.  Super useful!

Comment: Anything that requires to eject is an instant downvote. This is obviously an issue encountered 1) by a beginner, 2) in the early stage of the project. Two very good reasons NOT to eject.

Comment: why you do need to eject the app?

Comment: to add custom loaders to webpack @Andy

Comment: you can reach any customisations with the customize-cra, don't ya?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply
Looks like customize-cra is not maintaining. Last publish of customize-cra is for 3 years ago @Andy.

Comment: interesting, I went with customize-cra + react-app-rewired and then just used the `addLessLoader` in my `config-overrides.js` config file

Answer (score 13):

If you're using CRA, I would suggest going without ejecting.

First install `less`, `less-watch-compiler` and `concurrently`:

```
npm install less less-watch-compiler concurrently --save-dev
```

Then in your root directory create `less-watcher.config.json` and set the configuration:

```
{
    "watchFolder": "src/",
    "outputFolder": "src/",
    "runOnce": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "enableJs": true
}
```

Rename `App.css` to `App.less`

Replace start `script` in `package.json` with the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"less-watch-compiler --config less-watcher.config.json\" \"react-scripts start\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    ....
}
```

and run the application. Enjoy :)

Comment: This didn't work for me, I ended with the following problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366162/less-watcher-fails-to-load-less-file-import-like-import-third-party-lib-som

Comment: In late 2023 this does not work unless `"sourceMap": true,` is added to less-watcher.config.json. I've edited the answer above, it's a great answer!

Answer (score 9):

After upgrading my react to v 18 you can do it with react-app-rewired library without ejecting your whole config of react, it's more cleaner.

install react-app-rewired

```
npm i react-app-rewired
```

install less and less loader

```
npm install less less-loader --save-dev
```

change your scripts in package.json to

```
 "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",
```

after that you need a file named config-overrides.js in your main application folder to configure your application
you need to add this config

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module.rules[1].oneOf.splice(2, 0, {
    test: /\.less$/i,
    exclude: /\.module\.(less)$/,
    use: [
      { loader: "style-loader" },
      { loader: "css-loader" },
      {
        loader: "less-loader",
        options: {
          lessOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  })

  return config
}
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 5):

CRA (Create React App) by default supports only `SASS` and `CSS` if you want to use `LESS` you need to do `npm run eject` first and then modify `webpack` configs.

However there is a way to do that w/o ejecting tho I have to say I personally prefer ejecting. You can find instructions [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/using-less-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-510a3344ef5d)

Comment: Can you link a source that lists css and scss as only two supported options?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
npm i -D react-scripts-less
```

Then:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-less start",
    "build": "react-scripts-less build",
    "test": "react-scripts-less test",
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ruslan, this indeed solved the less problem for me as well! it should be marked as accepted answer for future reference. I despise these lazy SO users who don't mark the answer as accepted due to laziness.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{test:/\.less$/, use:['style-loader','css-loader','less-loader']}
```

Answer (score 0):

After ejecting and configuring the `webpack.config.js`, you also need to add the `less` file module declaration in `react-app-env.d.ts`.

```
declare module "*.less" {
  const content: { [className: string]: string };
  export default content;
}
```

Or you will get some error like this.

```
Cannot find module ‘xxx.less‘ or its corresponding type declarations. TS2307
```

Answer (score -2):

Is it relevant to use this method in large projects?

```
npm run eject
npm i less less-loader
```

Open `webpack.config.js` located at config folder created after eject script. Look at the return value of exported function (that's the main config). Find where last `style-loader` added which is `sass-loader`.

```
{
  test: sassModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders(
    {
      importLoaders: 3,
      sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
      modules: {
        getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
      },
    },
    'sass-loader'
  ),
},
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: getStyleLoaders(
    {
      modules: true,
      importLoaders: 3,
      sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
    },
    'less-loader'
  ),
  // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the containing package claims to have no side effects.
  // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
  // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
  sideEffects: true,
},
```