# How to use less.modifyVars in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less

I've found a online demo here:https://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/dPYxzR

want to use it in my React project, but somehow it is not working with React.

the less file:

```
@primaryColor: #006699;

.lessTest {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:@primaryColor;
}
```

Js file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import less from 'less'

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
        less.modifyVars({ primaryColor: "#ffe4e1" });
        less.refreshStyles();
  }, [])

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <div className='lessTest'>213</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

it seems modifyVars not working.

I've create a demo to explane :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twpmxg?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first question: Where does the `less` instance come from?
   In the project settings of the codepen, some javascript libraries are added, including `less.js`:
   [image]

2. How do I use `less.modifyVars` in my React project?
   First, you need to add `less` to your project (assuming you haven't already): [Using .less files with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749719/using-less-files-with-react)
   Next, add `less.js` to your React app's `/public/index.html` file:

```html
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.30.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, reference `less.modifyVars` like so:

```js
//Component.js(x)
window.less.modifyVars({ "cool-variable": red });
window.less.refreshStyles();
```

note: solution not tested

Comment: thanks for answer. here I've created a online demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twpmxg?file=src%2FApp.js , I tried another way to do it `var less = require("less");
` . it seems works , but still less.modifyVars() not working. can you have a look?