# Less watcher fails to load less file import like `@import '~@third-party-lib/some/package'` for third party library

Tags: reactjs, less, create-react-app

As another attempt to add Less support to my CRA application without ejecting I followed the tutorial here:
https://dev.to/chowjiaming/how-to-setup-less-with-react-without-ejecting-1nej

My **less-watcher.config.json** as in the tutorial above:

```
// less-watcher.config.json
{
  "watchFolder": "src/",
  "outputFolder": "src/",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "runOnce": false,
  "enableJs": true
}
```

Only to end with errors during `npm start` complaining about the imports found in some of my less files such as this one:

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './MyComponent.less'
...
```

**MyComponent.less**

```
@import '~@third-party-lib/something/dist/something'
```

This breaks upon `npm start` with error:

```
Config file my-project\less-watcher.config.json is loaded.
Watching directory for file changes.
Error: Command failed: lessc --source-map --js "MyComponent.less" "MyComponent.css"
FileError: '~@third-party-lib/something/dist/something' wasn't found. Tried src\components\MyComponent\~@third-party-lib/something/dist/something,... other places
```

but it doesn't look for it under the right place:
`node_modules/@third-party-lib/something/dist/something`

How would you fix this?